# What is the meaning of this sentence

Tags: learning, japanese-to-english

can someone translate the below sentence and explain the meaning of "射精しきって" for me?I'm reading H manga and stuck at this sentence

あっ！まだ射精しきってねえってのに...

Please explain it easily for me to understand. Sorry if my english isn't not good. Thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the off-chance that you aren't actually trolling...

The suffix きる means to complete an action fully. It is used with the continuative form (ます form without the ます). For する verbs this becomes しきる. And your example uses an informal version of しきっていない, indicating that the action hasn't been fully completed. I imagine you can figure out the meaning from there...

Comment: なるほど I understand now. Thank you so much ^^